# Target host refused sending email in C# smtp.gmail.com and Port No.587

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I am trying to send an email by building a console based application but whenever i try to run it it gives an error which says "Socket Exception: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 74.125.130.109:587" , can someone explain me what is wrong with my code or if not with my system settings?

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace Email
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program obj = new Program();
        obj.SendEmail("Just a Mock Message");
    }
    public void SendEmail(string emailBody)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("FromEmail.com","ToEmail.com");
        mail.Subject = "Testing my Application";
        mail.Body = emailBody;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",587);
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential()
        {
            UserName = "EmailExample.com",
            Password = "example123"
        };

        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(mail);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You are using Gmail SMTP port (TLS): 587 Try to use SSL port - Gmail SMTP port (SSL): 465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

smtp.gmail.com default port for SSL is 465. Try with

```
 SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",465);
```

Comment: I've tried using port 465 but the same error continues ! what should i do now?

Comment: `smtp.gmail.com`is opened for 465. Looks like you've been blacklisted by a firewall